# problems opening listView items with intents in android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I have a listView with 2 items in the list, the first item in position 0 responds to clicks but the other does not! i have tried to copy the same onclick method and changed the if statement to the list item in position 1 but it is not working out for me so i am looking how to get this working if someone could help me? i have included the only code i think is needed to resolve this,

```js
public class TopLevelActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_level);
        //Create an OnItemClickListener
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                        View v,
                                        int position,
                                        long id) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this,
                                                   DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            };
        //Add the listener to the list view
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    

      //what ive tried to open the foodCategoryActivity list item

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                        View v,
                                        int position,
                                        long id) {
                    if (position == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this,
                        
                        FoodCategoryActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            };
        //Add the listener to the list view
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently using two different click listeners for same ListView to do different on different items click in `ListView` with is not valid way to do task according to click position in ListView.

Use single click listener and inside `onItemClick` method use switch-case or if-else ladder for doing task like:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                    View v,
                                    int position,
                                    long id) {
                if (position == 0) {

                }
                else  if (position == 1) {{

                }
            }
        };
```

and also remove following line which you are using two times:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
```

because no need to create `listView` and call `setOnItemClickListener` multiple times just do it once.

Comment: ah so its a case of if else blocks then, say for example i have 8 items i should have them in nested if statements

Comment: @breakline: yes but i just copy code for example instead of text which i have written in my answer. ok now see my answer which is different codewise also

Comment: @james: if you have any issue with `if-else` block then use `switch-case`

Comment: tried this however the onitemclicklistener is in red, heres what i did... 
if (position == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this,
                                                   DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if(position==1){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this,
                                    FoodCategoryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                }
            };

Comment: sorry my bad,, missed the smallest of mistakes, being a closing brace, working fine

Answer (score 2):

You can only set one OnItemClickListener

you need to differentiate in the implemented method via either the position or the View object itself:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                    View v,
                                    int position,
                                    long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                  //code for drink category
                }
                else {
                  //code for food category
                }
            }
        };
    //Add the listener to the list view
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
```

Comment: how could i not have tried that already, thank you i shall give this a try